# Is there a way to ask about the status of a drag operation while it is in progress?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I know that when a drag/drop operation is completed, upon receiving a MouseUp or Esc key event, it returns an enum that indicates what happened (Move, Copy, None, etc.) My question is this: is there a way to send back status information to the form/control that initiated the drag event, *while* it is going on?

The use case is as follows (think Visual Studio-esque layout manager for all of this): I am writing a layout/window managing component that allows regions of the layout to be dragged around. I use a transparent form to paint a semi-transparent overlay that changes based on where the mouse is dragging over, a la the preview overlay that appears when dragging windows around in Visual Studio.

Another motivation is that the serialization process I describe is relatively resource intensive, and I'd prefer not to do it if the dragging is all going to occur within the same process/window. So, if there was a way to lazily serialize only when an actual "drop" in another window happens, that would probably make all the difference in usability.

What I want to do is enable dragging between different windows or even different instances of the application. I've already plumbed out the serialization code and everything, but the issue is that, when I drag a chunk of layout into another window, the first window doesn't have any way of knowing that the mouse is now over another instance of the application, which is more than capable of painting its *own* overlay. So, the original overlay hangs around like an idiot and my program looks like crap.

Is there any way for me to pass along some kind of callback or is there any message or property I can listen for/poll during a drag operation that will tell me if my mouse pointer is over a region that can accept its data? Please don't make me resort to listening for the CursorChanged event, I've already lost too much self respect using reflection to hack around weird wpf/winforms dragging interop bugs. If anyone could suggest a clean resolution for this problem I would be extremely grateful.

Additionally, if anyone could point me to any favorite sites which describe how to go about doing reeeeally funky things with drag and drop, it would be appreciated, as I've found there is quite a lack of really nitty gritty information available about dragging. Usual things like custom cursors and the like are okay, but I'm probably more interested in Win32 black arts and the like.

UPDATE:
I actually just found out about the GiveFeedback event a second ago, came back to my question, and there it was. Huge facepalm moment. However, since I've got you here, what about my second question: is there any way to lazily load the information only when it encounters a valid target? Could I somehow implement my own IDataObject or do things get marshaled righ when the mouse leaves the form? GiveFeedback provides me only with whether there's a valid target under the cursor, but doesn't let me change what data is being dragged...

ANOTHER UPDATE:
Is there any way to determine the source of a drag operation? That is, when my control receives a DragEnter message, how can I tell if the source of the drag is my own control or a foreign one? I know I can hackishly encode it by messing with the AllowedEffects property, but is there any more direct route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `GiveFeedback` event (there's a nice article [here](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/21573/0/page/3)) - that sounds to me to be exactly what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That does answer the main part of the question, and will let me hide the window just like I want to. Any idea about lazily loading data objects?